# Scan for instances of "self" calls within blocks in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c

Is there any script (or even a Regex) that can check for usage of "self" or underscored parameters within an Objective-C block in an entire project?

It's possible to skim over these accidentally when moving code, and I was wondering if anyone had a more bulletproof method for avoiding them.

---

EDIT: **For example,** function A should throw a flag but not function B... only within `^{}` does it matter in this case.

```
- (void)a
{
    ^
    {
        NSLog(@"This should throw a flag: %@ ... %@ ... %@", [self someProperty], _someProperty, self.someProperty);

        ^(NSInteger number)
        {
            NSLog(@"This should also throw a flag: %@ ... %@ ... %@", [self someProperty], _someProperty, self.someProperty);

        }(0);

    }

}

- (void)b
{
    NSLog(@"This is OK: %@ ... %@ ... %@", [self someProperty], _someProperty, self.someProperty);

    __weak NSObject *weakSelf=self;

    ^
    {
        NSLog(@"This is also OK.", [weakSelf someProperty], weakSelf, weakSelf.someProperty);

        ^(NSInteger number)
        {
            NSLog(@"This, too, is OK.", [weakSelf someProperty], weakSelf, weakSelf.someProperty);

        }(0);

    }

}
```

Comment: Why do you want to find accesses to `self` inside a block!?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you mean, but you can have the compiler put a warning triangle against every use of 'self' at build time by putting this in the 'Build Phases | Run Script' of your target:

```
TAGS="self"
find "${SRCROOT}/" -type f \( -name "*.h" -or -name "*.m" -or -name     "*.swift" \) -print0 \
| xargs -0 egrep --with-filename --line-number --only-matching "($TAGS).*\$" \
| perl -p -e "s/($TAGS)/ warning: \$1/"
```

Adjust the variables to suit.

Comment: Does this filter to within blocks? `^{}` or `^(NSInteger someVar){}`, etc.

Comment: Also, the underscored equivalent of `self` for properties `_propertyName`, etc.

Comment: You can add filter terms so that it'll look for more than one search term in the TAGS variable. e.g.,  `TAGS="self | _propertyName"`

Comment: I mean *any* underscored parameter (i.e. `_propertyName`) or instead of `[self propertyName]` or `self.propertyName`

Comment: Have you tried `TAGS="self | _*"` or try &-ing self with a wildcard and the underscore.

Comment: That might work, but what's filtering it to be within a block? the `^` character between one closure and another would most likely be the signal for that

Comment: It can be any number of blocks deep (nested) but just a single one is enough to throw a flag.

Comment: I added an example.